# When to use sequence files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I understand sequence files contain binary values.

Can you pls advise me when exactly sequencing should be used in map reduce.

I have found one mapreduce code from my friend wherein he has kept some MS Outlook emails in the HDFS.he was creating an email search application, so before doing indexing of emails he first converted them into sequence files.I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you want your MR job to process some custom serializable object which implements `Writable`.
For example you have in your system some object that represents a user.
This object (call it UserWritable for example) must hold many fields such as age name etc.  (maybe in a simple case it is enough to use Text and the user is represented by a comma delimited string,  but in most cases there would be more complex fields of types from your sytsem.. or maps/sets/lists).
In the above case `job.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);` is required.
Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for your explaination.Is it the case that indexing can be done on sequence files only?

Comment: Sorry but I am not familiar with indexing files for an MR job. HBase sounds more suitable for it